# How to chelude cgi bin scripts?

Tags: scripting, cgi, schedule, bin

i was wondering how do I schedule my script on cgi bin ro run every minute?
I tried to add cron job but it looks like either I don't know to to configure it properly or it is impossible to schedule these kind of scripts with it.

Comment: We can't tell why your cron job isn't working if you don't show us how it is set or or what the output from it is.

Comment: Why are you trying to run a CGI program on a schedule anyway? CGI programs are designed to run on demand when a URL is requested. Regular console scripts make more sense for scheduled tasks.

Comment: then how should i make my script run every minute on the internet?

Comment: Cron is the correct tool for that.

Comment: i enter: sudo crontab -e then i enter 1 * * * * /var/cgi-bin/echo.pl  and script is still not working every minute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
1 * * * * /var/cgi-bin/echo.pl
```

…will run the script at one minute past every hour, not every minute. Replace the `1` with a `*`.

Comment: many thanks, but I still can see my script updating with every refresh

Comment: What do you mean by "can see my script updating with every refresh"?

Comment: The script runs when you make a request to its URL (or call it from cron). Then a browser makes a request to its URL, it gets a response and then it renders that response. Having something else call the script again won't change the response the browser got in the past and cause the browser to rerender the page. That would be like ordering a banana from the supermarket and expecting the bananas in my neighbour's fruit bowl to vanish and be replaced by fresh ones.

Comment: okay, thaks for explanation. Maybe there is another way to do this?  Maybe my choice for cgi-bin was wrong?